# HTML Email - Outlook.com/Hotmail stripping all inline styles from img tags

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, hotmail

It appears that Outlook.com is stripping any and all inline styles from img tags. This is new to me. I know that outlook.com has been removing margins from images, but the old standby, display: block, is being completely removed. I have been experimenting with various styles, border, color, width, height, float. Nothing is coming through. I've tested this in various emails.

Has outlook.com made a change and is now not recognizing any inline styles on images? Has anyone else experienced this happening to their HTML emails? I work on HTML emails weekly, and today is the first time I have encountered this problem.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at their documentation.

Comment: @arkascha - Thanks, I will if no one else knows anything about it. I'm really looking for feedback from other HTML email developers who may have experienced the same thing/know why this sudden change. Also, I want to be sure it's not just me.

Comment: Please include an image tag both before and after. Are you using anything different like a `target="_blank"` or something that may (even though it shouldn't) be the x factor?

Answer (score 2):

As a HTML Email Developer, I think I can help you :)

So first of all, write all of your styles inline, then replicate your styles into external styles.

I have found this to work perfectly.

Also with the image, wrap it in a div and then style the div, and then set only HTML attributes to the img.

I hope this helps, if you have any questions, dont hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Does this answer your question my friend?

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding external styles, but outlook.com still will not recognize any of the styles applied to img. I have always been able to apply display:block to images to fix outlook.com spacing issues, today is the first time I've noticed it ignoring it. wrapping with divs doesn't seem to help with getting the image to display as block.